# order by descending by counting the arrays in parse.com using swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

so here is my parse data: 
[image]

i am saving all the data in an `NSMutableArray`

i tried this :

```
var dataQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
        dataQuery.orderByDescending("likes") // but this doesn't make sense at all.
        dataQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
```

i want the post at the top having maximum number of `likes` and so on. How can i do that? Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 3):

This is not directly possible. But you can add a likesCount property an update it via cloud code on every save.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Posts", function(request, response)
{
    var likes = request.object.has("likes") ? request.object.get("likes") : [];
    request.object.set("likesCount", likes.length);
    response.success();
});
```

Then use the `likesCount` property :

```
var dataQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
dataQuery.orderByDescending("likesCount")
// ...
```

Comment: where can i add this cloud code? :| i am a beginner,.

Comment: Nice answer, good idea and cool concise use of `has` and the ternary operator.  Wish I could +2.